# serialize a binary tree in python with one input parameter

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have the following code for serialize and deserialize a binary tree

This is a simplified version of an interivew practice.

I want to only use primitive python construct
without additional pkg loaded and recursion.

Any pointers to site is really appreciated.

I am not sure this site keep asking for more details.

```
def serialize(Node):
    """ONLY_USE_PRIMITIVE_PYTHON_CONSTRUCT_AND_RECURSION"""
    return str

def deserialize(str):
    """ONLY_USE_PRIMITIVE_PYTHON_CONSTRUCT_AND_RECURSION"""
    return Node


class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data
    #def printTree(self):
    #    print(self.data)
    def insert(self,data):
        if self.data:
            if self.data > data :
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif self.data < data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data
    def printTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.printTree()
        if self.right:
            self.right.printTree()
        print(self.data)

def serialize(Node, serial):
    if Node != None:
        serial.append(Node.data)
        serialize(Node.left, serial)
        serialize(Node.right, serial)
    else:
        serial.append('x')

def deserialize(serial):
    root = Node(None)
    ptr=0
    data_len=len(serial)

    if(data_len>0 and serial[ptr]!='x'):
        root.insert(serial[ptr])
        ptr=ptr+1
    elif (data_len==0 or serial[ptr]=='x'):
        return root


    while(ptr<data_len):
        if(serial[ptr]=='x'):
            ptr=ptr+1
        else:
            root.insert(serial[ptr])
            ptr=ptr+1

    return root
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `data`? Can it be anything? Only integers? Strings? Complex data types?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the `data` are integer values. Even if this is not the case, it will not be so hard to adapt the code below.

There are of course many ways to serialize. If you need to avoid a second argument to the `deserialize` function, then it is helpful if you know at which offset in the serial string the data of the right child starts.

So here is a suggestion:

```
def serialize(node):
    if node is None:
        return ""
    left = serialize(node.left)
    right = serialize(node.right)
    return str(node.data) + ":" + str(len(left)) + ":" + left + right

def deserialize(serial):
    if serial == "":
        return None
    data, leftsize, content = serial.split(":", 2)
    node = Node(int(data))
    node.left = deserialize(content[0:int(leftsize)])
    node.right = deserialize(content[int(leftsize):])
    return node
```

Comment: root = Node(12)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(3)
root.printTree()

Comment: data=serialize(root)
print(data)
print(data)
uu=deserialize(data)
uu.printTree()

Comment: That just works fine for me. See that example run [here](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/SerializeTree).

Comment: 12:8:6:4:3:0:14:0:

Comment: It is an encoded string length. The thing with serialization is that it does not need to be human-readable. It just needs to guarantee that it can be deserialized to the original object. And that is what it does.